# Abstract base class that inherits ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections, interface

Suppose I have an abstract base class `BaseTimeCollection` and at least one concrete class `ConcreteTimeCollection` which inherits from the base class.

I would like my base class to inherit from `ICollection<T>`.

Inheriting from `ICollection<T>` requires me to provide implementations for a number of methods, including `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` and `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator`.

I do not want to implement these methods in `BaseTimeCollection` - instead I would prefer to implement them individually in each of my concrete classes.

This is where I run into trouble.

The `GetEnumerator` methods need to be declared explicitly, because there are two of them both with the same name but different return types. 
However, it seems that as soon as I make the signature explicit I can no longer use the abstract modifier. Essentially I am forced to implement the `GetEnumerator` method in my base class.

```
public abstract class BaseTimeCollection : ICollection<Time>
{
    abstract IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator();  // compile error: The modifier    'abstract' is not valid for this item
    abstract IEnumerator<Time> IEnumerable<Time>.GetEnumerator(); // compile error: The       modifier 'abstract' is not valid for this item
}

public class ConcreteTimeCollection : BaseTimeCollection
{
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
       // this is where I would like to provide my implementation for IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    }

    IEnumerator<Time> IEnumerable<Time>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // this is where I would like to provide my implementation for IEnumerable<Time>.GetEnumerator()
    }
}
```

1. What have I missed?
2. Is there some way I can defer implementation of the `GetEnumerator` methods to the concrete classes?

Comment: What is the compile error you are getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily defer the implementation to your child classes by having the explicit implementations call protected abstract methods in your abstract class and then letting the children implement those abstract methods:

```
public abstract class BaseTimeCollection : ICollection<Time>
{
    protected abstract IEnumerator IEnumerable_GetEnumerator();
    protected abstract IEnumerator<Time> GenericEnumerable_GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() 
    { 
        return IEnumerable_GetEnumerator(); 
    }

    IEnumerator<Time> IEnumerable<Time>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GenericEnumerable_GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Sorry for the poor naming scheme...it's the best I could come up with this early in the morning.

Comment: That looks like it should do the trick - thanks! Seems quite obvious in hindsight :)

Comment: No need to have two abstract implementations, since the non-generic implementation can call the generic abstract method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: What is the compile error you are getting?

Do you need your base class, maybe you can just use another interface like:

```
public interface BaseTimeCollection : ICollection<Time> {}
```

and then have your implementations implement that interface instead of your base class, or do you have some common functionality?

Comment: For the sample code in my post the compile error I get is "The modifier 'abstract' is not valid for this item". This error points to the two abstract method declarations in the base class. Yes I do have some common functionality that has been omitted from the example.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to implement both versions of GetEnumerator explicitly to prevent the name clash, so unless there's another requirement for them both to be explicit, you could make the generic method implicit so that it can also be abstract. Then, as per @supercat, the non-generic method can call the generic one.

```
public abstract class BaseTimeCollection<Time> : ICollection<Time>
{
    public abstract IEnumerator<Time> GetEnumerator(); // implicit, generic and abstract

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    // Other ICollection methods (Add, Clear, etc) ...
}
```